# Using google_maps_cluster_manager package to cluster a map

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am new using flutter. I have a project that requires clustering multiple locations on map and I came accros this cluster packages where the below are imported

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/google_maps_cluster_manager.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'place.dart';
```

My problem is the `import 'place.dart'` Icant't find file and the code.

please can anyone help?
If the pace.dart should be a model, what should the constructor look like?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a place.dart, [place](https://github.com/bpillon/google_maps_cluster_manager/blob/master/example/lib/place.dart), like in example:

```
class Place {
  final String name;
  final bool isClosed;

  const Place({required this.name, this.isClosed = false});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Place $name (closed : $isClosed)';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, I will try this and get back.